# Full Fourier Series in Polar Coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, polar-coordinates

Suppose $\phi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ . Assuming the necessary conditions, then its

1. **Full Fourier series** on $[-l, l]$ is
   $$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{2}A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\cos\big(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\big) + B_n\sin\big(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\big)$$
   where
   $$A_n = \frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^l \phi(x) \cos\big(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\big)dx, \quad B_n = \frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^l \phi(x) \sin\big(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\big)dx$$
2. **Fourier Cosine series** on $[0, l]$ is
   $$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{2}A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\cos\big(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\big)$$
   where
   $$A_n = \frac{2}{l}\int_{0}^l \phi(x) \cos\big(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\big)dx$$
3. **Fourier Sine series** on $[0,l]$ is
   $$\phi(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n\sin\big(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\big)$$
   where
   $$B_n = \frac{2}{l}\int_{0}^l \phi(x) \sin\big(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\big)dx.$$

Based on my readings I was under the impression that formulas transfer practically identically to polar coordinates. That is,

1. **Full Fourier series** is
   $$\phi(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\cos\big(\frac{n\pi \theta}{l}\big) + B_n\sin\big(\frac{n\pi \theta}{l}\big)$$
   where
   $$A_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \phi(\theta) \cos\big(\frac{n\pi \theta}{l}\big)d\theta, \quad B_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \phi(\theta) \sin\big(\frac{n\pi \theta}{l}\big)d\theta$$
2. **Fourier Cosine series** is
   $$\phi(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\cos\big(\frac{n\pi \theta}{l}\big)$$
   where
   $$A_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \phi(\theta) \cos\big(\frac{n\pi \theta}{l}\big)d\theta$$
3. **Fourier Sine series** is
   $$\phi(\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n\sin\big(\frac{n\pi \theta}{l}\big)$$
   where
   $$B_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \phi(\theta) \sin\big(\frac{n\pi \theta}{l}\big)d\theta.$$

However in my experience of using Fourier series to solve PDEs using separation of variables, this does not always seem to be the case (for example, page 167 in Strauss's text *Partial Differential Equations* and [these notes from Brown](https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am34/Mathematica/ch6/polar.html) disagree on the coefficient when solving Laplace's equation on the exterior of a circle, [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) also has the coefficient of a full series as $1/\pi$, does Strauss have a typo?). I sometimes see that the scalar in front of the integral defining the coefficients to be $2/\pi$ and other times $1/\pi$. Which one is correct, or is it done on a case by case basis?

Comment: I think in the second set of formulae, $l$ should be $\pi$.

Comment: @Gary What if I wanted to use a sine or cosine series on all of a disk? How would I account for $\theta \in [\pi, 2\pi]$?

Comment: Your $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: @Artem Now I am perhaps more confused, as the references I am using sometimes define the integral bounds as $[\pi, \pi]$ and other times as $[0, 2\pi]$, is there a reason for this?

Comment: It does not matter, because the resulting series is periodic with period $2l$ in general, and it is a simple matter to show that $\int_{-l}^l f=\int_{-l+a}^{l+a}f$ for any $a$.

Comment: @CBBAM What do you say about my comment? The second set of formulae after "Based on my readings..." are special cases of the first ones when $l=\pi$. There is not $l$ in there anymore. Fix that!

Comment: @Artem Thank you, I figured the intervals $[-\pi, \pi]$ and $[0, 2\pi]$ due to functions' invariance under that translation. What I am more confused about is that for the full (polar) Fourier series, some texts have the scalar in front of the integral in each coefficient as $1\pi$ (as in the case of Cartesian coordinates) but other texts have it as $2/\pi$.

Comment: @Gary Wouldn't they equivalent? If not, would you be able to explain why or point me to some sources?

Comment: Which book has the coefficient $2/\pi$?

Comment: @Artem Strauss' text "Partial Differential Equations, An Introduction", first edition, page 167

Comment: On page 167 there are formulas that start with $a^n/\pi$, where $a$ comes from the boundary condition. I do not see any formulas with $2/\pi$ there.

Comment: @Artem Thank you for checking, to be sure we have the same version this is the example regarding the Laplace's equation on the exterior of a circle correct? I bought a very old copy, could be that mine has some errata.

Comment: Yes, it is first edition, Example 3: The Exterior of a Circle.

Comment: @Artem I suppose I will consider it errata then and take the coefficient to be $1/\pi$ whenever a full Fourier series is used. Thank you for the help.